# I want to call JavaScript setInterval function only once after window load

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function hidemap(){
    $('#mapToday').hide(); 
    $('#mapWeek').hide();
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
var myVar;
$(window).on('load', function() { 
    myVar = setInterval(hidemap, 2000);
});
```

I want that this code should call only once. But now its calling after every 2 seconds.

Comment: `setTimeout` is your friend :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **entire** point of `setInterval` is to call something *every* n seconds.

If you want to call a function *once* after some time has passed, use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `setTimeout`.

```
function hidemap() {
    $('#mapToday').hide();
    $('#mapWeek').hide();
    clearInterval(myVar);
}

var myVar;

$(window).on('load', function() {
    myVar = setTimeout(hidemap, 2000);
});
```

Also, since `hidemap` does not return anything, you should do this:

```
function hidemap() {
    $('#mapToday').hide();
    $('#mapWeek').hide();
    clearInterval(myVar);
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(hidemap, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

need to use clearInterval in hidemap function

try below code

```
var myVar;
function hidemap(){
    $('#mapToday').hide(); 
     $('#mapWeek').hide();
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }

 $(window).on('load', function() { 
     myVar = setInterval(hidemap, 2000);
  });
```

or use setTimeout function

```
var myVar;
function hidemap(){
    $('#mapToday').hide(); 
     $('#mapWeek').hide();
    clearTimeout(myVar);
  }

 $(window).on('load', function() { 
     myVar = setTimeout(hidemap, 2000);
  });
```